# How to check for upgrade readiness on Windows Server 2008

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008

I want to **upgrade** Windows server 2008 to 2016. I know I have to go through server 2012 first. so I need to check for upgrade readiness and compatibility issues before proceeding.

There is azure **upgrade readiness** for windows 7, 8 and 10 devices. But I want to check UR for Windows Server 2008.

Is there any tool for it? Best if there will be any way to check it in Azure UR.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is an Azure tag on this question, i will mention that Azure doesnt support server upgrades. You need to create new vm and migrate workloads.

Comment: ok is there any tool to check for application compatibility for Windows server 2008 clients

Comment: not sure i understand the question. easiest way to verify you app works on 2016 - create a 2016 VM (takes 5 minutes) and install your app.

Comment: I have 40 windows server 2008 systems. can imagine the number of applications that they are using. Need a tool like application compatibility tool (ACT).

Comment: i wouldnt trust any such tool anyway. unless its MS app and MS released the tool

Comment: Yes but ACT does not support windows servers.